# How to draw a directed graph in matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a matrix with ordinal numbers like below. I want to connected the nodes as you see in this picture. this is a directed graph. I have MATLAB 2015a. how can i draw graph like this and put it on my image with ?[image]
as you see in the picture the node number one in (4,8) is should connected to the other node with directed graph. and node number2 should connect to other except node number 1 and so on( the node should connect to node with bigger number)

Comment: How is the direction of each connection and which node is connected to which determined? There is an edge from `i` to `j` if `i<j`?

Comment: the direction rule is: the smallest numbers directed to the biggest numbers.

Comment: Suppose your image is same size as the matrix on the upper left. First, plot your image e.g. using [`imagesc`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html). Then use [`find`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the row and column subscripts of the nodes. Finally, apply your connection rule to plot lines from/to the appropriate nodes' row and column coordinates to others using e.g. [`line`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html).

Comment: the both matrix is the same. and yes i know to use find command to get all axis of the nodes. but how to draw that directed graph? you mean use "line" command?

Comment: Could you add that information and maybe some code indicating your current progress to the question to make it easier to help you?

Comment: @mikkola : thanks. you said :"Finally, apply your connection rule to plot lines from/to the appropriate nodes' row and column coordinates to others using e.g. line" but how can i do that?i know i can use digraph but digraph not worked on matlab 2015a. it is on 2015b.

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19580-plot-a-directed-graph--v2-0-), or [biograph](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/biograph.html)

Comment: @Miki. thank you.GPLOTDC is not recognized in my matlab? why?

Comment: Have you downloaded the script and put it in your path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Miki: thanks for your answer.(Check out [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19580-plot-a-directed-graph--v2-0-), or [biograph](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/biograph.html))